# Zombie section headers in indexed list

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made indexed list according to [this apple tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html), but I have problem with deleting items. When I delete last item in section at the bottom, the section header remain there. This happens only with last section.

[image]

Here is my code for deleting item:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {  
        [[self.littleWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```

littleWords is array of sections same as states in apple tutorial.

code for making cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView
                             dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyBasicCell"];

    Word * myWord = [[self.littleWords objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = myWord.name;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = myWord.translation;
    return cell;

}
```

rest of tableView functions:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [self.littleWords count];

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [[self.littleWords objectAtIndex:section] count];

}



- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionIndexTitles];

}



- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if ([[self.littleWords objectAtIndex:section] count] > 0) {


        NSString *str = [[[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionTitles] objectAtIndex:section];

        NSLog(@"returning section header: %@", str);
        return str;

    }

    return nil;

}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index

{

    return [[UILocalizedIndexedCollation currentCollation] sectionForSectionIndexTitleAtIndex:index];

}
```

Comment: what is your code to generate cells?

Comment: @isaach1000 I add it in question

Comment: Ok that seems fine. What about the code for the section titles?

Comment: I just added the rest of UITableView functions. I try to log which values titleForHeaderInSection returns. The zombie section headers wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the method `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. The number should change when you delete all of the items in a given section. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSInteger sections = 0;
    for (NSArray *sectionArray in littleWords) {
        if (sectionArray.count > 0) {
            sections++;
        }
    }
    return sections;
}
```

**Edit:** After deleting the row, you may need to call `[tableView reloadData]` or a similar methid to update the sections.

Comment: unfortunately this isn't working. Program even doesn't show all my items... but thanks for your effort